# LINQ for two tables where date range between two values

Tags: linq, c#-3.0

Folks i have an issue coming up with the correct syntax  in LIQ to get the items in the ITEM table that are not reserved in the ITEMRESERVED table for a date range.

```
For Example: Item contain:
ItemID   ItemName
1        A
2        B
3        C


ItemReserved Contains:
ID     ItemID    StartDate   EndDate
1      1         06/06/14    07/06/14
```

Table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Item](
[ItemID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ItemName] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ItemID] ASC
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ItemReserved](
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ItemID] [int] NOT NULL,
[StartDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
[EndDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)

[FK_ItemReserved] FOREIGN KEY([ItemID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Items] ([ItemID])
```

Based on the following search details:

Select all items in the ITEM table from not reserved between 06-06-14 & 07-06-14

Code so far:

```
var StartDate = DateTime.Now;
var EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

var query = from i in db.Ttem
            join ir in db.ItemReserved
            //on i.ItemID equals ir.ItemId - This line brings back the data that is reserved
            on i.ItemID (??? != ) ir.ItemId
            where i.ItemID == ir.ItemID //&& (Dates <= Start and >= End)
            select i;
```

This code works for selecting what is reserved for the dates but not i need the reverse of it, whats not reserved?

```
 var StartDate = dpStartDate.SelectedDate.Value;
 var EndDate = dpEndDate.SelectedDate.Value;

 //LINQ - To get all cars from database
 var query = from i in db.Item
             join ir in db.ItemReserved
             on i.ItemID equals ir.ItemID
             where i.ItemID == ir.ItemID && ((StartDate >= b.StartDate) && (EndDate <= b.EndDate))
             select i;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
// Declaration of start and end date.
var StartDate = DateTime.Now;
var EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

// Get the items in db.Ttem that are reserved in the time period
// between StartDate and EndDate.
var query = from i in db.Ttem
            join ir in db.ItemReserved
            on i.ItemID equals ir.ItemId 
            where ir.StarDate >= Start && ir.EndDate<= End
            select i.ItemID;

// Get the items in db.Ttem that are not reserved in the time period
// between StartDate and EndDate.
var result = db.Ttem.Where(x=>!query.Contains(x));
```